# Can't permanently add tag "x-window-system" to list of interesting tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

1. I add the tag "x-window-system" to the list of interesting tags by typing in the box and pressing "Add".
2. The tag appears in the list of grey boxes.
3. I reload the page.
4. The tag "x-window-system" has gone.

Also, there seem to be a lot of equivalent tags, xwindows, x11 and xwindow. The most popular one is "x-window-system" but I can't add that to the interesting tags.

Comment: not sure you meant to make this wiki :)

Comment: @waffles: I make every question and every answer which I post to meta.stackoverflow.com community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag `x-window-system` will be remapped to `x11`

I added the `x-window-system` tag to my interesting tags list, refreshed the page, and it was swapped to the `x11` tag.

[image]

Comment: This answer said "Jeff Atwood" and then suddenly it says "Barry".