# Highlight tag synonyms as such

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-highlighting

In response to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63676/cant-permanently-add-tag-x-window-system-to-list-of-interesting-tags/63678#63678), I was thinking that we should maybe highlight all tags that will be automatically re-mapped to another tag.

We should probably add a Legend on to SO to state what the highlighting mean (similar to the Legend on MSO)

[image]

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62871/146482, esp. the mock-up http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62871/separate-tag-fields-to-prevent-split-tags-warn-on-tag-creation/63209#63209

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be necessary.

Tags that are designated as synonyms of other tags *should not appear in the system* except in the synonyms area (I think it's debatable whether accepted synonyms should appear in the autocomplete, but that's a separate discussion). The only reason why they do appear is because when a synonym is accepted, the existing questions are not automatically retagged.

Tags with synonyms that need merging appear by filtering the synonyms list by [the "merge" item](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=merge&tab=newest). This should make it easy for mods to keep on top of what tags need to be merged.

Comment: so for the tag `x-window-system` why does it appear in the auto complete boxes?  Shouldn't it display the synonym instead.  So we are sort of prompting the user with the tag that really want. Does it mean that the 43 questions that have been tagged with `x-window-system` should be retagged `x11`

Comment: @Barry: As I said, it's debatable. And yes to the second question.

Comment: Well I think I may retag those questions. Shall I ask a separate question asking for the auto complete changes?

Comment: @Barry: Yes, please start a separate question for that discussion. Thanks.