# Display tag synonyms differently in the tag browser

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-synonyms

[image: Image of tag and tag synonym]

Is `[bugs]` a tag with one question, or a tag synonym? Can't tell... can you? This is a real problem when trying to manage tags.

**Please differentiate tag synonyms in the list, possibly with a different border.**

Comment: One solution might be to just add (s) after the tag instead of the xX, like they do in the tag autocomplete to indicate a synonym.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63694/highlight-tag-synonyms-as-such

Comment: also (slightly) related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62871/146482

Comment: Well, if we were to follow established naming conventions, the singular is corret; the plural is incorrect; and a synonym is not required.