# Please identify tag synonyms more clearly on the Tags page

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface

At the moment, the pages that come up under the Tags tab display synonyms at the end of the list. There's little indication that they're synonyms; they look just like any tag that's used once. Only alphabetization on the page where the single-use → synonym switch occurs gives any indication that certain tags are synonyms at all.

We already identify tags that are used multiple times by appending a number, like "**× 574**." Can we append something similar for synonyms, like "**× 0**" or "**(s)**"?

Comment: Oddly titled, but [this is roughly asking for what you want](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64750/display-tag-synonyms-differently-in-the-tag-browers), if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: related: [Separate tag fields to prevent split tags, warn on tag creation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62871/146482)?

Comment: @Grace, I suppose that's close enough. Searching is a somewhat different use case than just browsing the full list, but if others want to close, I won't fight for a reopen.

Comment: Fixing one should implicitly fix the other, aye? Searching is just browsing a filtered subset of the full list, after all.

Comment: @Grace, if you say so; I only use the tags list once every few weeks, if that. Seems plausible, though.